# How can I get the clients information that access an exact page?

Tags: php, api

So, I have this code, which is from a plug-in that I want to create:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

use Ubnt\UcrmPluginSdk\Service\UcrmApi;
use Ubnt\UcrmPluginSdk\Service\UcrmSecurity;
use Ubnt\UcrmPluginSdk\Security\PermissionNames;

chdir(__DIR__);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/main.php';

$fullAddress = isset($_GET['fullAddress']) ? $_GET['fullAddress'] : '';
$firstName = isset($_GET['firstName']) ? $_GET['firstName'] : '';
$lastName = isset($_GET['lastName']) ? $_GET['lastName'] : '';

// GET collection of clients
$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];
//echo sprintf('Found %d clients.', count($clients)) . PHP_EOL;

// GET the client data that access the 'Contract' page
foreach($clients as $client) {
    $response = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest(
        sprintf('clients/%d', $client['id']),
        'GET',
        [
            'fullAddress' => $fullAddress,
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
        ]
    );

    if($response !== null) {
        echo sprintf('The following details are for client number: <b>%d</b>', $client['id']);
        echo '<ul>';
                echo sprintf('<li>%d</li>', $client['id']);
                echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $client['fullAddress']);
                echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $client['firstName'] . ' ' . $client['lastName']);
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo sprintf('There was an error retrieving data from client: %d.', $client['id']) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo 'Done.' . PHP_EOL;
```

For now, if I run this code and I click on the plug-in's page I get this:

[image]

What I am trying to is: I want to recieve only the client's information that access the page.

So, I am logged as a client (each client have access to that page named **Contract**) and when I click on **Contract** page I want to get my client information, not of all clients.

I've tried to modify :

`$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];` > `UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest(sprintf('clients/%d', $client['id'])` and remove the foreach, but then I got an error that `$client` is not defined.

Comment: Is a login necessary to get to this page?  IF YES,  Then there is usually the user id of the logged in user in the session and then you can just echo the data belonging to that client.  Now you are just echoing ALL clients.  In the readme of the library there is an explanation about getting the user that is logged in.   (  $user = $security->getUser();  )      https://github.com/Ubiquiti-App/UCRM-Plugin-SDK/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You said " I am logged as a client ". How are you doing that?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig, I have used the technique that is explained in the README, but if I use `$user = $security -> getUser();` then I can not access the page as a client, because is not an admin. The plugin that I want to create is only for the client.
@icalvete, I can switch to **client zone** (I go to **Clients** then select a client and on the client page I have **view as client**.

Comment: There are public information about the Class/Method UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest ? What README are you talking about?

Comment: @icalvete, I posted the UCRMAPIAccess Class as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$clients` variable is an array that contains a list of all the clients that have accessed that page, as you're getting the collection here:

```php
$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];
```

And I believe you're trying to get the one client that just accessed the page, since you said:

> "when I click on Contract page I want to get my client information, not of all clients"

Then I believe you can filter the `$clients` array for a single client that matches an id, ONLY if you know the id of the client you're looking for.

For example:

```php
$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];

$you = (object) array('firstName' => 'foo', 'lastName' => 'bar', 'id' => 1);

$meInClients = array_filter($clients, function($k) {
    // filter by key
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)

$clients[meInClients]
```

But in this case it seems your program doesn't know what user to look for, so a filter or search might not work here. What you want to do is get the last user who JUST visited that page, naturally that user would be the last in the array.

So:

```php
$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];

$whoJustVisitedPage = $clients[count($clients) - 1]
```

So this might work.

UPDATE:

When you access the page as John Doe and go to that page, ( the $clientsWhoVisitedPage array now becomes $clientsWhoVisitedPage + YOU (currently authenticated user a.k.a the last person who viewed the page) What you can do in this case is first to filter the $client array so it doesn't contain the currently authenticated user. Then get the last user in the new array.

Like so:

```php
$me = $security->getUser();

$clientsExceptMe = array_filter($clients, function($client, $x) {

    return $client->id != $me->id;

}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));

$lastPageVisitor = $clientsExceptMe[count($clientsExceptMe) - 1]
```

`lastPageVisitor` should now give you the last person that visited that page that isn't the currently authenticated user.

Comment: It worked, it's receiving the information from one client, but, for example, when I am logged as **John Doe** I access the page, I get the information for **John Doe**, but after that I logged as **Jane Doe** and I access the page, I still get the information for **John Doe**.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but it seems like it's a different issue you're facing now. Do you want the `$whoJustVisitedPage` variable to hold the value of the currently authenticated user? or you want it to hold the value of the last user to have visited the Contract page?

Also if the answer helped you can mark it as the solution for that first problem, to help others.

Comment: Yes, the `$whoJustVisitedPage` to hold the variable of the currently authenticated user, that's what I am trying to explain, but I am sorry if you didn't get it first time, it was my bad, haha.

Comment: Oh, I understand you now, so here's what's happening, I'm going to use abstract terms so you understand on a high level:
- When you access the page as John Doe and go to that page, ( the `$clientsWhoVisitedPage` array now becomes `$clientsWhoVisitedPage + YOU (currently authenticated user a.k.a the last person who viewed the page)`

What you can do in this case is first filter `$client` array so it doesn't contain the currently authenticated user. Then get the last user in the new array.

Comment: I'll update my initial answer to show an example

Comment: [image](https://i.gyazo.com/7162fecf6586427842323cad1279093a.png) - I get this, because of `return $client -> id != $x-> id;`.

Comment: @matei_ can you var_dump the value of `$security->getUser();`

Comment: [look here](https://i.gyazo.com/7a4f3fa839c0f6394b2222117ce1eedd.png) to see the value of var_dump($me);.

Comment: Okay cool, try doing this: replace the line that throws that error with this:

`return (object) $client->userId !== (object) $x->userId`

Comment: so I solved the errors by modifying `return (object) $client -> userId !== (object) $x -> userId` into `return (object) $client['id'] !== (object) $x['id'];`, but I still got the same information of the client that accessed the page already, as I said before. [look here to see the code](https://i.gyazo.com/93e8129babb5ca853eb217281f460e86.png).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code of *UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest*, so I can not help you with this aproach although is the rigth one. (Search Doc about this Class/Method)

As a really shit solution, you can do something like this ...

```php
$fullAddress = isset($_GET['fullAddress']) ? $_GET['fullAddress'] : '';
$firstName = isset($_GET['firstName']) ? $_GET['firstName'] : '';
$lastName = isset($_GET['lastName']) ? $_GET['lastName'] : '';

// GET collection of clients
$clients = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest('clients') ?: [];
//echo sprintf('Found %d clients.', count($clients)) . PHP_EOL;

// GET the client data that access the 'Contract' page
foreach($clients as $client) {
    $response = UCRMAPIAccess::doRequest(
        sprintf('clients/%d', $client['id']),
        'GET',
        [
            'fullAddress' => $fullAddress,
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
        ]
    );

    if($response !== null 
         && $firstName == $client['firstName']
         && $lastName == $client['lastName']
         && $fullAddress == $client['fullAddress'] 
      ) {
        echo sprintf('The following details are for client number: <b>%d</b>', $client['id']);
        echo '<ul>';
                echo sprintf('<li>%d</li>', $client['id']);
                echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $client['fullAddress']);
                echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $client['firstName'] . ' ' . $client['lastName']);
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

echo 'Done.' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: When I use your code, I do not get any information at all, only the `Done.` message.